# Convert Array into Object with filtering and prioritizatoin and minimum loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, filter, reduce

Given an array

```
const array = [{
  typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 1, value: 'Welcome'
}, {
  typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour'
}, {
  typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'portrait', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour bonjour'
}]
```

My ultimate goal is to get this:

```
{
  welcome: {
    landscape: ['Welcome'],
    portrait: ['Bonjour bonjour']
  }
}
```

To do that, I need to convert into object like `{typeName: {orientation: value[]}}`, like this:

```
// This is NOT what I want, it's just an intermediate form -- keep reading
{
  welcome: {
    landscape: ['Welcome', 'Bonjour'],
    portrait: ['Bonjour bonjour']
  }
}
```

**But** including prioritization: if languageId=1 present on array, then ignore rest values for specific typeName, orientation..In the sample above should be only **['Welcome']** since it's languageId=1, so **'Bonjour'** can be ignored, though if languageId=1 is missing, then any value can be added (welcome.portrait).

With convering I haven't faced with any problems..Doing it thought [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method

```
array.reduce((prev, current) => ({
    ...prev,
    [current.typeName]: {
        ...prev[current.typeName],
        [current.orientation]: [
            ...(((prev[current.typeName] || {})[current.orientation]) || []),
            current.value
        ]
    }
  }), {});
```

but prioritization I can do only with filtering that also does loop inside it..No problem so far, but if array will be pretty huge - performance will suffer

```js
    const array = [{
      typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 1, value: 'Welcome'
    }, {
      typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour'
    }, {
      typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'portrait', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour bonjour'
    }]

    const result =  array
      .filter((item) => {
          return item.languageId === 1 ||
          !array.some((innerItem) => ( //Inner loop that I want to avoid
              innerItem.typeName === item.typeName &&
              innerItem.orientation === item.orientation &&
              innerItem.languageId === 1
          ))
      })
      .reduce((prev, current) => ({
        ...prev,
        [current.typeName]: {
            ...prev[current.typeName],
            [current.orientation]: [
                ...(((prev[current.typeName] || {})[current.orientation]) || []),
                current.value
            ]
        }
      }), {});
      
console.log(result)
```

So the question is what's the best approach to avoid inner loop?

Comment: What if you see `languageId` 2 first, followed by 1? Can you assume it will be sorted?

Comment: Just a side note: You seem concerned about performance with large arrays. Note that the code you have creates lots of temporary objects that it then throws away almost immediately, which can create memory pressure when dealing with large data sets. You don't have to do that (even if you use `reduce`, but there's no reason to use `reduce` here...or almost anywhere else ;-) ).

Comment: Good question @Ja͢ck. My answer allows them to be in any order, but I might be able to shave off a branch if I knew they'd be sorted.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I get this data from API, which is getting from DB, so I can get a sorting list by languageId in both orders

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you please elaborate a bit about using reduce and memory pressure?

Comment: @MaxZavodniuk - Just to be clear, those are two separate things. :-) About memory pressure: Creating objects and throwing them away is memory churn, making work for the garbage collector, which can impact perf. About `reduce`: It's overcomplicated in the general case. If you use functional programming and have a library of standard reducer functions you reuse, `reduce` can make sense; otherwise, use a loop. A good rule of thumb is: If you're passing an inline function into it, use a loop instead. (I'm with [Brian Terlson](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) on this.) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Set` to keep track of whether you've seen a `languageId === 1` for a particular `typeName` and `orientation`. `Set` is [required to have sublinear performance](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set-objects):

> Set objects must be implemented using either hash tables or other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection.

So a `Set` will outperform an inner loop. (You could also use an object if your keys are strings, which they are in my example below. If you do, create it with `Object.create(null)` so it doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`.)

Then just a single straightforward loop rather than `reduce`:

```js
const array = [{
  typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 1, value: 'Welcome'
}, { typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 1, value: 'Bon dia'
}, {
  typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour'
}, {
  typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'portrait', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour bonjour'
}]

const sawPriority = new Set();
const result = {};
for (const {typeName, orientation, languageId, value} of array) {
    const key = `${typeName}-${orientation}`;
    const isPriority = languageId === 1;
    let entry = result[typeName];
    if (!entry) {
        // No entry yet, easy peasy
        entry = result[typeName] = {[orientation]: [value]};
        if (isPriority) {
            sawPriority.add(key);
        }
    } else {
        const hasPriority = sawPriority.has(key);
        if (hasPriority === isPriority) {
            // Either the first for a new orientation, or a subsequent entry that
            // matches the priority
            const inner = entry[orientation];
            if (inner) {
                // Subsequent, add
                inner.push(value);
            } else {
                // First for orientation, create
                entry[orientation] = [value];
            }
        } else if (isPriority) {
            // It's a new priority entry, overwrite
            entry[orientation] = [value];
            sawPriority.add(key);
        }
    }
}

console.log(result)
```

(In a comment, you mentioned that if there are multiple `languageId === 1` entries, they should be built up in an array, so I've included a second one in the above to show that working.)

---

In the above, I'm comparing two boolean values like this:

```
if (hasPriority === isPriority) {
```

That works because I **know** that they're both actually booleans, not just truthy or falsy values, because `isPriority` is the result of a `===` comparison (guaranteed to be a boolean) and `hasPriority` is the result of calling `has` on `Set` (guaranteed to be a boolean).

If there were any question about whether one of them might be just a truthy or falsy value rather than definitely `true` or `false`, I'd've used `!` on them to ensure they were booleans:

```
if (!hasPriority === !isPriority) {
```

Comment: love your approach, but one issue is here, that I probably wasn't clear with.. The result on lower level is array, because it can be multiple values for languageId=1, so if I would add 3rd element to array
  `{
    typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 1, value: 'Bon dia'
  }` it will replace Welcome( 1st element), but should be 2 `...{landscape: ['Welcome', 'Bon dia']`

Comment: @MaxZavodniuk - Ah, yes, that changes the logic slightly. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `Set` for prio items and prevent adding more items to the array.

```js
const
    array = [{ typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 1, value: 'Welcome' }, { typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour' }, { typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'portrait', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour bonjour' }],
    hasPrio = new Set,
    result = array.reduce((r, { typeName, orientation, languageId, value }) => {
        var key = `${typeName}|${orientation}`;

        if (!r[typeName]) r[typeName] = {};
        if (languageId === 1) {
            r[typeName][orientation] = [value];
            hasPrio.add(key);
        } else if (!hasPrio.has(key)) {
            if (!r[typeName][orientation]) r[typeName][orientation] = [];
            r[typeName][orientation].push(value);
        }
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for your version, but I was probably unclear in original post. The result on lower level is array, because it can be multiple values for languageId=1, so if I would add 3rd element to array { typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 1, value: 'Bon dia' } it will replace Welcome( 1st element), but should be 2 ...{landscape: ['Welcome', 'Bon dia']

Answer (score -1):

See live demo [here](https://runkit.com/embed/pcsu0pjd9nvf)

```js
const array = [{
  typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 1, value: 'Welcome'
}, {
  typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'landscape', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour'
}, {
  typeName: 'welcome', orientation: 'portrait', languageId: 2, value: 'Bonjour bonjour'
}];


let obj = array.reduce( (acc, {orientation, value})=>{   
      acc[orientation] = (acc[orientation] || []).concat(value);
      return acc;
   }, {});

output = {};
output[array[0].typeName] = obj;   
console.log(output);
```